# Problema al hacer un INSERT con la clausula OUTPUT

Tags: mysql

quiero insertar un **familiar** y que me devulva el ID para insertar en la tabla imagenes la imagene que introdujo el cliente en el **form**, para ello estoy intentando usar la clausula **OUTPUT**:

```
INSERT INTO familiares(nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,fecha_nacimiento,lugar_nacimiento,fecha_fallecimiento,lugar_fallecimiento,oficio,datos_destacables,biografia)
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES ('jose','apel_1','apel_2',NULL,'mi_ciudad',NULL,'mi_otra_ciudad','mi_oficio','mis datos destacables','nacio y murio el mismo dia');
```

pero me esta dando **error de sintaxis**, quiero que me devuelva unicamente el id del **familiar insertado**.

Comment: Hasta dónde sé, la clausula `OUTPUT` es de SQL Server y lamentablemente no existe en `mysql`

Answer (score 3):

La clausula `OUTPUT` es nativa de **`SQL Server`** y lamentablemente no existe en **`MySQL`**. Sin duda, para lo que estás buscando sería muy útil, ya que permite "capturar" los id´s autonuméricos recién insertados en una tabla secundaria, ya sea que insertes una fila o cientos. No hay forma de reemplazar está funcionalidad.

Si bien existe [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) con el cual podrías eventualmente hacer algo así:

```
INSERT INTO familiares(nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,fecha_nacimiento,lugar_nacimiento,fecha_fallecimiento,lugar_fallecimiento,oficio,datos_destacables,biografia)
    VALUES ('jose','apel_1','apel_2',NULL,'mi_ciudad',NULL,'mi_otra_ciudad','mi_oficio','mis datos destacables','nacio y murio el mismo dia');

INSERT INTO imagenes(familiar_id, ...)
       values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ...);
```

Es un arma de doble filo, tiene varias consideraciones y limitaciones:

- Te retorna el primer `ID` autonumérico generado de la última sentencia `insert` ejecutada en la conexión activa.
- Obviamente funciona en tablas que tengan este tipo de columnas
- Al insertar múltiples filas, solo se reflejará el primero de los `id` insertados
- En caso de error, el valor es indefinido, eventualmente podría corresponder al último `id` de otra tabla
- Si en una columna autonumérica se inserta un valor explícito, esto no se refleja en el  `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Dicho lo anterior, entiendo que la forma más sencilla y consistente de resolver lo que preguntas, es mediante el uso de [`triggers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). El siguiente es un ejemplo de dos tablas, la primera con un autonumérico y la segunda dónde insertamos estos `id´s` luego de haberse generado:

```
drop table if exists prueba1;
drop table if exists prueba2;

create table prueba1( id int primary key );
alter table prueba1 change column id id int auto_increment;

create table prueba2( id int primary key, fecha_insert datetime );

\\
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON prueba1
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    -- insertamos en prueba2 el o los id recién insertados en prueba1
    INSERT INTO prueba2 
        SET id = NEW.id,
            fecha_insert = NOW()
    ;
  END;
\\

-- insertamos dos filas dummy
insert into prueba1 values (null), (null);

select * from prueba1;

╔═══╦════╗
║ # ║ id ║
╠═══╬════╣
║ 1 ║ 1  ║
╠═══╬════╣
║ 2 ║ 2  ║
╚═══╩════╝

select * from prueba2;

╔═══╦════╦═════════════════════╗
║ # ║ id ║ fecha_insert        ║
╠═══╬════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 1  ║ 19.06.2019 23:44:33 ║
╠═══╬════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ 2  ║ 19.06.2019 23:44:33 ║
╚═══╩════╩═════════════════════╝
```

En un entorno multiusuario, tienes que entender que no siempre tendrás garantizados los mismos datos de la `tabla1` en el momento en que los vayas a copiar a `tabla2`. Los `triggers` se ejecutan en una transacción implícita, lo cual te garantiza al menos la consistencia de los datos, entre las dos tablas, para cualquier otra alternativa, deberás considerar el uso de las transacciones explícitas.

Comment: mmm Pero un trigger en un entorno multiusuario, como me asegura que estoy viendo el registro que yo inserte?

Comment: @gbianchi, el trigger se ejecuta dentro de una transacción implícita, el segundo insert si se hace usando la pseudo tabla `NEW` debiera tener garantizada la misma información, esto si, habría que aclararlo.

Comment: perfecto... de acuerdo..

Answer (score 2):

creo que esto es lo indicado para que te devuelva el id que necesitas

```
INSERT INTO familiares(nombre,apellido_1,apellido_2,fecha_nacimiento,lugar_nacimiento,fecha_fallecimiento,lugar_fallecimiento,oficio,datos_destacables,biografia)
VALUES ('jose','apel_1','apel_2',NULL,'mi_ciudad',NULL,'mi_otra_ciudad','mi_oficio','mis datos destacables','nacio y murio el mismo dia');

select LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

puedes saber mas en la documentación de mysql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: ¿Que hace el `LAST_INSERT_ID()` dentro del insert? lo que se quiere es en todo caso es obtener es último id insertado luego del insert.

Comment: en efecto amigo , no es que no exista en mysql , si hay solo que el metodo es muy diferente el metodo que mas se parece en una funcion de php que lo vi en Zend Framework

Comment: Si, ok, pero revisa el ejemplo que has dado, por que sintácticamente esta mal. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` debe ejecutarse  luego del insert

Comment: lo acabo de hacer , y me ha devuelto el id en mysql

Comment: No me has entendido, ya te modificado el código de tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias , como me puse a leer la documentacion y me devolvia el ID pense que era lo que buscaba

Answer (score 1):

pues la idea que se me ocurre para resolver esto consistiría en devolver el máximo ID de la tabla familiares. Si dicho id lo tienes definido como un AUTO_INCREMENT, el valor del id del ultimo familiar añadido para despues utilizarlo en el INSERT de la tabla imágenes lo puedes obtener de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT MAX(ID) FROM familiares; #Devuelve el ID del ultimo familiar insertado en la tabla
```

De esta forma te devolverá el ID del ultimo familiar que hayas insertado que es lo que estas buscando. Ahora únicamente tienes que hacer la inserción en la tabla imágenes y debería de funcionar.

Un saludo

Comment: si no fuera un escenario multiusuario.. mira si justo se ejecuto otro insert en el medio y esto devuelve el id del otro...

Comment: Cierto, pero siempre puede implementarlo como una transacción (y hacer que se ejecute una tras otra con lo cual habría una menor concurrencia) o puede implementarse como un trigger y también se ahorra ese problema

Comment: Ejemplos???? si no parece a medio camino la respuesta...